# Mysql error in query: ... near ' '

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application which takes the information of a mysql database(a music-db) and shows it via echos in a div. Everything works fine.

Now I wanted to add a search bar so you can search the database for a specific song.

The search bar just loads a php file with a mysql query. The word or the letters you want to search for are passed via a varbiable in the link(for example test.php?searchvalue=it).

Now my problem: I get the following Mysql-error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

The quotes in the error are single quotes!

The Query is:

```
$searchvalue = $_GET["searchvalue"];

$query = mysql_query("select SongID, Songtitel, artwork, duration, SCID from tMusic where Songtitel LIKE '%$searchvalue%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Why is this wrong?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Escape your PHP variable using `mysql_real_escape_string` then when you have time update your code to use PDO or mysqli_ functions.

Comment: Also, is Songtitel mean to be spelt that way?

Comment: Can you print the query actually sent ? This will help the debugging process...

Comment: I tried the mysql_real_escape_string but it still doesn't work. Yes the Songtitel is spellt right - german...

Comment: The query sent is: `select SongID, Songtitel, artwork, duration, SCID from tMusic where Songtitel LIKE '%it%'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchvalue = $_GET["searchvalue"];

$query = mysql_query("select SongID, Songtitel, artwork, duration, SCID from tMusic where Songtitel LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($searchvalue)."%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Oh ya. that was good so others knows how they are mistack. sure from next will be take care of that

Comment: Does anyone know the reason of the name `mysql_real_escape_string` ? Is there an "unreal" version of the function?

Comment: beacuse it will escape the unusable string to prevent sql injetion

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php *"mysql_real_escape_string() takes a connection handler and escapes the string according to the current character set. mysql_escape_string() does not take a connection argument and does not respect the current charset setting"* @Amarnasan

Comment: Really? Oh,my... that reminds me when I create an improved new function 'foo' as 'foo2'... so sloppy. What if there's an improved version? `mysql_really_really_escape_string'  ?